# Is it possible to call the constructor of a class in another class?

Tags: java, constructor

If i have two classes in differents files,not in the same file,
and in particular, not connected by inheritance.

```
public class Hello{
  Hello(){
    System.out.println("HELLO");     
 }
}
public class GoodBye{
  GoodBye(){
    Hello.Hello();       
 }
 public static void main(String arg[]) {
       new GoodBye();
 }
}
```

Comment: Copy paste your code, compile it, don't panic, let us know.

Comment: That's weird to call "Hello" from "GoodBye" :/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

definitely

```
public class GoodBye{
  GoodBye(){
    new Hello();      
 }
}
```

Comment: ahaha, as @Hrishikesh says , when i call the constructor , i create a new instance of the class,i forgot that.

Comment: @GyroGearless may be most of the people take a "correct answer" *seriously* (my answer was not humor)

Comment: @sanbhat Surely its somewhat correct in a technical sense. But i suppose questioner has a lack of understanding that a constructor is not a normal method, but only used to initialize an object. I#m afraid your answer does not add much enlightenment here...

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. Wouldnt you create a String object in your constructor ever?

```
public class GoodBye{

 public  GoodBye(){
    Hello hello = new Hello();           // This is your class object
    String aString = new String("aString"); // This is a string object. 
 }
```

The reason why i mention String here is because, there is absolutely no difference if you create an object of your own class or a class provided by the Java runtime. 
When you use the `new` operator you are instantiating an Object of the Class. That is all there is to it.

Comment: `new String(String)` is not exactly instructive. We never use that.